# Really matted hair

Tags: hair

I have extremely matted hair! it’s really bad it causes headaches when down and is too painful to pull up into a bun or a ponytail. It is also painful to brush and wash. i’ve tried conditioner and lube but nothing works. i don’t know what to do.

Comment: Can you include a photograph? You can hide your face if you want, but if we could see your hair we could probably give you better suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

How about cutting it short? (I just don't see why you'd keep it long if it is so problematic.)

Comment: That may not be a viable solution, due to social constraints.  The OP may be female (considering the username), and in a number of societies and subcultures, a woman having short hair can send social cues that she may not want to send.

Even if it's just personal preference, it's good to know how if there's a solution that may not be as onerous as the routes you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue until I began to comb the conditioner through my hair (before I rinsed the conditioner out). Over time, I suggest that you begin to use a conditioner that deep conditions once a week or so (it is worth the extra cost), and leave it in your hair, to prevent this issue. I no longer get small mats in my hair at all, and I no longer have to comb conditioner through my hair.